# is mysql connector module can run in another pc

Tags: python, mysql-connector

first of all, sorry for this dumb question.

secondly, this is the scenario, i made executable file from `python`, my app need to connect to `mysql` database, in my app script is using `mysql.connector`.

thirdly, what i want to know, is my app can run and connect to `mysql` database in another pc that does not have `mysql` driver installed? *because of poor resource, right now i can't just try and find out my self.

if it can't, can i using `sqlite` and then all the pc client data saved in 1 file database that place in shared folder, so 'admin' can read it anytime?

thank you so much

Comment: If you create something like an executable from this working code it will grab all of the necessary imported modules. So, yes, in this case it will work on similar devices.

Comment: @JustinOberle, thank you mister, that is so relieving.

Comment: Are you using pyinstaller to generate the exe? If so, I can confirm that it'll work since the imports in your app will be included when generating the executable.

Comment: @Stoobish yes, then you have saved my day for overthinking sir, because when i submitted my project, iam not really sure about this matter. thank you

Comment: i don't know why your question today was closed.  I have a good answer for you and now I can't post it.  How to show correct data from divs when you click button.  I will share if you can post question again. and let me know here